# Relation between Magnetisation $\vec M$ and magnetic flux density $\vec B$

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, magnetic-moment, ferromagnetism

I saw that magnetisation $\vec M$ and magnetic flux density $\vec B$ are related by the equation

$$\vec B = \mu_0\vec M, $$

From where does this equation comes, where can I get a proof of this equation?